# Probability to win one prize in 5 draws from 100 tickets with one prize for each draw

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that you hold one of the 100 tickets in a lottery.  There are 5 prizes altogether, 1st prize for the first draw, 2nd prize for the second draw, etc.  Assume the draws are without replacement.  Find the probability that you win one prize.

My attempt: 
1/100+1/99+1/98+1/97+1/96. 
Not sure if this is correct. Please help

Edit: or would it be $\dfrac{5 \choose 1}{100 \choose 5}$?

Comment: really? isnt that too complex for such a simple question?

Comment: i really dont understand. can you please help me? how come i cant just do  1/100+1/99+1/98+1/97+1/96

Comment: I realized that misread the problem. It's not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you hold one ticket, the five prizes must be chosen from the other tickets. Thus the probability that you do not win any prize is $\dfrac{\binom{99}{5}}{\binom{100}{5}}$ and the probability that you win one prize is $1 - \dfrac{\binom{99}{5}}{\binom{100}{5}}$

Answer (score 1):

There are $5$ numbers drawn, the probability you have one of these five is simply $\dfrac5{100}=\dfrac1{20}$.

Comment: how come it isnt,  1/100+1/99+1/98+1/97+1/96?

Comment: because you need to consider that you didn't win first prize, so it starts 1/100+99/100.1/99+...=1/100+1/100+...=1/20

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that your ticket number is $1$.

The probability that you don't win a prize is the probability that a $1$ is not chosen in $5$ draws without replacement. This is:

$$ P(\mathrm{No \; Prize}) = \prod_{i=1}^5 \frac{100-i}{100-i+1} = \frac{99}{100}\frac{98}{99}...$$

Subtract this from $1$ to get your probability of winning.

Comment: how come this solution is different than the other two guy's solutions?

Comment: @AnthonyDesjardins the question is not completely clear, as you can tell from my initial comments. When I read it carefully, I interpreted it as you having 5 chances to have your number drawn (without replacement) from a basket of 100 unique numbers.

Comment: @AnthonyDesjardins the others are assuming that there are 5 prizes in the basket and you are trying to draw one of them. That was my first interpretation and it leads to a different answer.